# Create internet-password and specify where field

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, keychain

I've been able to create an internet password but when opening the password in Keychain, I don't see the where field. Any ideas how to specify this?

`security add-internet-password -a "foo" -s test.com -w "bar12345"`

I've reviewed https://ss64.com/osx/security-internet.html, but unable to see how to specify the where field.

Answer (score 3):

oh wait, just got it working myself...

`security add-internet-password -a "foo" -s test.com -w "bar12345" -r 'htps'`

If specifying `-r htps`, you specify the protocol which results in the entry being correctly created and the where field being populated as https://test.com. This wasn't too clear in and related searches I did.

Comment: How did you manage to find out that 'htps' stands for 'https'?

Comment: trial and error :) I also found an unrelated reference after which I then tried it. Makes no sense and I couldn't find documentation on it, but it worked.

Comment: The four-letter codes for the protocols are constants listed in [SecKeychain.h](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Security/Security-57740.1.18/OSX/libsecurity_keychain/lib/SecKeychain.h.auto.html) (where you can see that `kSecProtocolTypeHTTPS` is "htps"). Yes, I found it very hard to track down, too.